# Preimage of an affine subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V,W$ be general $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces and let $A=v+U\subseteq W$ be an affine subspace. Let $\varphi:V\to W$ be a linear mapping.

I need to show that the preimage $\varphi^{-1}(A)$ is an affine subspace of $V$ or empty.

I went on to write elements of $A$ as $v+\sum_{i=0}^k\lambda_ib_i$ for $k$ distinct basis vectors. My problem is that $\varphi$ is not nec. a bijection and thus we don't have a unique $x\in V$ s.t. $\varphi(x)=v+\sum_{i=0}^k\lambda_ib_i$.

Comment: Do you mean $\varphi(v)=v+U$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be the linear map associated to $\varphi$, show that if $\varphi^{-1}(A)$ is not empty and contains $x$, $\varphi^{-1}(A)=x+L^{-1}(U).$

If $x'\in x+L^{-1}(U)$, $x'=x+v, v\in L^{-1}(U)$ you deduce that $\phi(x')=\phi(x)+L(v)\in A$, conversely, let $y\in \varphi^{-1}(A)$, write $y=x+u$, you have $\phi(y)=\phi(x)+L(u)\in A$ implies that $L(u)\in U$ and $y\in x+L^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: I don't quite get the role of $L$, why introduce another linear map?